# Activate view automatically in a page

Tags: drupal-7

I wonder how I can create a view and activate it at any given time to automatically see on a particular page , just with some option in the administrator to ativate it.

Maybe could use also nodequeue ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having a little trouble understanding what you mean, but let me put in some starting points.

Views UI submodule allows you to go to /admin/structure/views and see the list of views, and enable/disable each right there.  Disabling this module on production sites is recommended, but few developers do because it is annoying to have to turn it on and off when you want to make little adjustments.

As far as "at any given time to automatically see on a particular page" it sounds like you want Panels, Context, and to make the Views as Panel displays.  This would allow you to use one particular page (the url registered to the panel) that has all your created views on it, perhaps with selections rules to change which ones are visible depending on who is looking or whatever other trigger you want.

Now with the details from your comment:
It sounds like what you want is a Taxonomy vocab set to tag style, so that any user can add terms to it.  Taxonomy already has pages for each term, where it lists the nodes that have that term.  You could improve this with a view that uses a Context filter to find the term and the related nodes.  With this in place, the same view can display as many pages as the users have terms, each with a url like /collection/[term]  where "collection" is the url the view sits at, and [term] is the part that the view reads for the filter.
Now, as soon as any user tags an article with a new term, a page is "made" for that term and can show all articles with the same term.

Comment: What I try to explain:

What I really need is a user other than an administrator can create in a specific place page.tpl.php a block with some tag articles and creating all this somehow activated and displayed. Also esta block can contain an image header.